# What happen if showDialog of activity get called ? Does activity call onPause if yes why ?

Tags: android

What happen if showDialog of activity get called ? 
Does activity call onPause if yes why ?  As it is the part of Activity only then why onPause gets call?

Comment: ShowDialog means any AlertDialog from your activity?

Comment: you can try for yourself: Override the onPause and onResume method and include a System.out.println("paused") or something similar there. As far as I remember (and that's why i'm posting this as a comment not an answer) it's just the focus you loose, but it does not pause.

Comment: Are you just curious? Or do you have an actual problem? If you're just curious, try it out, like @stefan told. Otherwise, tell us what's the question is

Answer (score 1):

onPause() isn't called on activity that showed dialog.

onPause() is called when your activity is no longer at the top of the activity stack. A Dialog by itself is not an Activity, so will not replace the current Activity at the top of the stack, so will not cause anything to pause.

A dialog (lower-case) does not need to be implemented by a Dialog class, however. For example it is not uncommon to implement one with an Activity whose theme is set to that of a dialog. In this case displaying the dialog-as-an-Activity will cause the new Activity to be on the top of the stack, pausing what previously was there.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240916/android-under-what-circumstances-would-a-dialog-appearing-cause-onpause-to-be)