# confused between returning to activity and navigating to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I'm a bit confused with Android lifecycle. This is the transition diagram for reference: https://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Consider this scenario: Activity is running -> another activity comes into the foreground -> onPause(). At this point, isn't the current activity no longer visible as another one has already come into the foreground? However, the diagram indicates that there are following cases:

1) onPause() -> user returns to the activity

2) onPause() -> activity is no longer visible -> onStop() -> user navigates to the activity

What's the difference between these flows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266417/difference-between-onpause-and-onstop

Comment: Think about a message you got on the screen, which hides partially your activity => onPause. Lets say you clicked that message and your messaging app is now taking the entire screen --> onStop()