# Why my activity's onStop() is not getting called only onPause() is getting called even when my activity is completely not visible?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have an activity `MainActivity` from where I am opening an activity `TransactionActivity` but the problem happening with me is why my `MainActivity's` `onStop()` method isn't getting called only `onPause()` is getting called. I have seen this post on SO [difference-between-onpause-and-onstop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266417/difference-between-onpause-and-onstop), and here in answers it is written that when some part of your activity is still visible then `onStop()` will not gets called the only `onpause` will get called but for my case as `MainActivity's` is completely not visible why it's `onStop()` is not getting called ??

Is this happening because of some `Activity leak` or **anything which is causing my Activity to stay in memory** even when it is completely not visible ??

Anyone, please enlighten me what is happening here ??

My **Code** for calling `TransactionActivity` from `MainActivity`

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TransactionActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("trans_type", 0);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your AndroidManifest.xml, Maybe you have set a transparent theme.

Comment: Yes Mine was the theme problem, I removed translucent theme

Answer (score 1):

Check your activity style . the item "windowContentTransitions" is true will let the

Answer (score 0):

When you call another activity from your previous one, it is placed "beneath" the new one.
So once you back press, previous activity will be shown. 
This is default bahavior in Android.

onStop is only called when a activity is finished.
So you could, for instance, call ActivityA.finish() after a startActivity(ActivityB).

Still not really sure why you need code in your onStop method. This is dangerous since system itself can call onStop if it needs to free some memory. There's probably a better way to do what you are trying to achieve.

Good luck!

Comment: No, onStop() gets called when activity becomes completely invisible you can see that in the post I have mentioned in my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266417/difference-between-onpause-and-onstop

Comment: For some Android 9 devices the `onStop` method is not immediately invoked when another activity is presented (previous one becomes completely invisible). Its invokation is delayed by a few seconds and occurs while the user is seeing the new activity.