# How i can find out that the user has left the app. Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

everybody, I want understand when user left the app. Language Kotlin. (Sorry for error)

Comment: probably listen for the lifecycle events of an activity, onPause, onStop, onDestroy are usually used to enquire the those info about leaving app or activity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between onPause() and onStop() of Android Activites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266417/what-is-the-difference-between-onpause-and-onstop-of-android-activites)