# Listener to detect whether a view is at the front?

Tags: android, focus, android-view, android-window

I have `RecyclerView` and, in some cases, I show another view on top of it - `ProgressDialog`, `AlertDialog` or `DialogFragment`.

Is there some way to notify me about cases when my `RecyclerView` is at front or another view is above it now?

I tried to add `onFocusChangeListener()` to my `RecyclerView`, but no luck.

PS. Definitely, I can in my `RecyclerView` create some method `isOnFront(boolean onFront)` and in all my other views call it, but maybe there is some more elegance way?

Comment: I have tricky solution, If your cases are just like displaying `ProgressDialog`, `AlertDialog` or `DialogFragment`, then you should override `onPause()` and `onResume()` of activity or fragment where your `Recyclerview` is implemented. Showing dialog will call onPause() method, and dismissing that dialog will call `onResume()` of that activity, from this you will able to know whether `Recyclerview` is in focus or not.

Comment: No, that won't work, as I show dialog from the same activity. Moreover, as dialogs should be modal, I add them via `FragmentManager.add()` instead of `FragmentManager.replace()`. So `onPause()` is not calling at all.

Comment: Ok so for fragment you can work on backstack count. You can figure out whether fragment is present or not.

Comment: If you show `AlertDialog`, for instance, fragments' backstack would not be changed.

Comment: To whom has this problem, this helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65005551/8551764

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProgressDialog`, `AlertDialog` and `DialogFragment` would lay their content on the `Window`, **not** to your activity's/fragment's view hierarchy. Which means, that as soon as either of them is shown, the focus of `Window` is changed. Hence, you can make use of [`ViewTreeObserver#addOnWindowFocusChangeListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#addOnWindowFocusChangeListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowFocusChangeListener)) API:

```
    contentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnWindowFocusChangeListener(
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowFocusChangeListener() {
          @Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
            // Remove observer when no longer needed
            // contentView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnWindowFocusChangeListener(this);

            if (hasFocus) {
              // Your view hierarchy is in the front
            } else {
              // There is some other view on top of your view hierarchy,
              // which resulted in losing the focus of window
            }
          }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try!

Comment: Yes, this makes a trick, but one small thing - `addOnWindowFocusChangeListener` needs API level 18. Any idea for earlier APIs?

Comment: I suppose [`getWindow().getCurrentFocus()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getCurrentFocus()) will do the trick. It will return `null` if there does **not** exist a view with a focus.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rethink your software design. If YOU trigger dialogs to be shown on top of another views, then you SHOULD know if the are shown or not. Another question is: Why should your `RecyclerView` know something about other views in your application?

If you really want to know, if your dialog is shown or not, set a boolean variable in your Fragment (or Activity), when you show it. Or use the field itself as indicator (`myDialog != null` equals "myDialog is shown"). Set it to null if you dismiss your dialog. If you really need to let other `Fragments` or `Views` know, that you show a dialog on top of them you can use any kind of event bus to broadcast this event.

I do not recommend tampering with any kind of ViewTreeObserver listeners or FragmentBackstack listeners for getting this result.