# How can Service determine, if UI visible now

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-activity

I try to make Notification which must work only when Application UI **isn't** visible.
I tried to store preference which was written in `onStart()` and `onStop()` of my `Activity`. But sometimes, it's not working because another application became visible without `MyActivity.onStop()` being called.

What other method I can use for a Service to determine, if MyApplication is visible now?  Or, maybe MyActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have code to keep track of the **state** of your app's UI, you can probably get it to work simply by putting the code in `onPause()` and `onResume()`, instead of `onStart()` and `onStop()`.

It is possible for the UI not to be visible, or partially hidden, even before `onStop()` gets called ... as you found out.

Take a look at the Android Activity lifecycle diagram here:

http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

and note [the description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

> The **foreground lifetime** of an activity happens between a call to
>   `onResume()` until a corresponding call to `onPause()`. During this time
>   the activity is in front of all other activities and interacting with
>   the user. An activity can frequently go between the resumed and paused
>   states -- for example when the device goes to sleep, when an activity
>   result is delivered, when a new intent is delivered -- so the code in
>   these methods should be fairly lightweight.

[Read more about this in another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11387258/119114).

Comment: Yes, it's the simplest way and I will try it. Thank You!