# how to kill application when user click home button?

Tags: android

I developed an application, especially for Exam, this app disallows students to use the back button (will clear its data and cache) and the Recent App button also disabled, but this app has a weakness: Students still can open another application (e.g Browsing) when they click the Home button.

I tried to do like this in the **onStop** method

```
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    this.finish();
    clearApplicationData();
}
```

And this is the code of the **clearApplicationData** method :

```
public void clearApplicationData() {
    File cache = getCacheDir();
    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
    if (appDir.exists()) {
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for (String s : children) {
            if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                Log.i("ERROR", " File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not working, the app can still be opened and the data isn't cleared
Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried overriding `onPause` instead of `onStop`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11387395/19224040

Answer (score 0, accepted):

way 1.

```
getActivity().finish();
System.exit(0);
```

way 2. API 16 -> new

```
this.finishAffinity();
```

way 3. API 21 -> new

```
finishAndRemoveTask();
```

Comment: I tried but the code is not supported, finishAffinity and finishAndRemoveTask showing red line below. but System.exit is worked, thank you Javatar..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to be aware of the `android lifecycle` you can know more about per `android lifecycle`  when the user clicks the home button and then call the `onPause()` method.

- You can do like below

  ```
   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   clearApplicationData();
   finishAffinity(); 
  }
  ```

`finishAffinity()` This method kills all process of the application and then reopen the application to start with a new process