# Asynctask cancelled when interstitial ad shown

Tags: android, android-asynctask, ads

I have an Asynctask in my app that runs a process in the background to load a website and retrieve information from it. During this I show a loading dialog.

While the process is working, I show an interstitial (full screen) ad.

**EDIT:** When this ad is shown (not necessarily when the x is pressed), the app *cancels* my Asynctask.

I'd like the ad to not cancel my Asynctask.

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Parsing website...");
            ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
            links = pullLinks((String) params[1]);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.setLocalStoragePath((String) params[0]);
            // Get desktop versions only
            config.setBrowserUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4");
            Goose goose = new Goose(config);
            Article article = goose.extractContent(links.get(0));
            return article.cleanedArticleText();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String webText) {

        // Allow rotation
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
        Log.i(TAG, "EXECUTED");
        if (webText.equals(""))
            handleSendText(UNSUPPORTED_WEBSITE);
        else
            handleSendText(webText);
        dialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(webText);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        lockOrientation();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(PasteActivity.this, "Add",
                "Getting article from website, please wait...", true, true,
                new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        LongOperationTask.cancel(true);
                        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
                    }
                });
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Toast.makeText(PasteActivity.this, "Adding cancelled.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

Another edit: Adding:

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Does not fix this either.

Edit: Removing:

```
LongOperationTask.cancel(true);
```

Does not fix this either.

Edit: So I realized that the interstitial ads actually call onPause() on my activity. And in my onPause I cancel my task. I'm attempting to move the cancellation of the task to onStop() instead. But this isn't ideal.

Update: Does not fix this either. But the task appears to keep running once I cancel the ad. However a few seconds later it is still cancelled.

Comment: I believe this question would benefit from showing more code, at least the lifecycle callbacks from your activity so other members can figure out what is going on. Also, your ad [shouldn't cause onPause() to be called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240916/android-under-what-circumstances-would-a-dialog-appearing-cause-onpause-to-be), isn't that right?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `AsyncTask` is linked to your `Activity` (your `AsyncTask` instance is probably an attribute of your `Activity` - otherwise show us how they are related to each other so we can help out). Thus when you recreate your `Activity` (e.g. by doing `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED)`) the `AsyncTask` reference is lost (garbage-collected) and it stops running.

My suggestion in order to keep the `AsyncTask` running throughout orientation changes is to follow the pattern shown in [this sample project](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/09/10/asynctask-screen-rotation.html) (the way it is done is a bit outdated though, in the case you are using `Fragments`, but it is simple and works).

Comment: Actually even forcing orientation to portrait only (i.e. no rotation possible), the task gets cancelled while the ad is showing.