# Activity's onpause method not getting called after showing AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have tried below code to check Activity's call backs, As of my understanding whenever dialog comes on top of Activity, Activity's `OnPause()` method should call. When dialog disappears Activity's `OnResume()` should trigger.

Surprisingly it's not happening the way it should work.I have tested on Android M 6.0.1

Please correct me if I am wrong, Here is my code,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onResume");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
        } else {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        }
        builder.setTitle("Delete entry")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // continue with delete
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't use your `AlertDialog` at all! use `.show()` or your `onClick` class in `onCreate`.

Comment: You wouldn't get such callback unless and until their is activity with dialog theme.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have tried below code to check Activity's call backs, As of my
>   understanding whenever dialog comes on top of Activity, Activity's
>   OnPause() method should call. When dialog disappears Activity's
>   OnResume() should trigger.

NO. [Documentation is bit confusing](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onPause()). When you call a dialog on top of activity, `onPause()` of activity will never call. Think it in other way, dialog always tied-up with calling activity, and if that activity in not in running state, how that dialog would be visible?

Actually, `onPause()` will only call when you are calling another **activity as dialog (using dialog theme, or an activity which does not cover full screen)**.

---

From documentation

> [**onPause()**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onPause())

- A new, semi-transparent activity (such as a dialog) opens. As long as the activity is still partially visible but not in focus, it remains paused.

---

You can also read [Android: Under what circumstances would a Dialog appearing cause onPause() to be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240916/android-under-what-circumstances-would-a-dialog-appearing-cause-onpause-to-be)

Answer (score 8):

**onPause()** is called when your activity is no longer on top of activity stack. A `Dialog` by itself is not an activity, so will not replace the current activity at the top of the stack, so **onPause()** is never called.

However if you implement `Dialog` as an `Activity` : (An activity which has a theme set to that of a dialog). In this case when displaying dialog as an activity will cause the new activity to be on top of the stack, hence calling **onPause()**